# ubuntu stuck at GNOME

Tags: gnome

after installing some python project dependency my ubuntu got crashed and i am not able to login my ubuntu got stuck after "started GNOME display manager".please suggest me the solution to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question and add a bit more information such as Ubuntu version, Python version, and overall what commands you used and exactly you tried to install. Adding any error logs Would also very help to understand the problem better.